# Why "undefined: StackGuardMultiplierDefault" error?

Tags: go, glide-golang, golang-migrate

#### describe

When I clone `GoAdminGroup/go-admin` projectin `github` and run the project by the steps of `README.MD` file , I get this error

```
TEST-MBP:example TEST$ GO111MODULE=on go run main.go
go: downloading github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.11.0
go: extracting github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.11.0
go: finding github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 v1.11.0
# runtime/internal/sys
/Users/TEST/go/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go:16:30: undefined: StackGuardMultiplierDefault
```

Actually my `/Users/TEST/go/src` folder was cloned from https://github.com/golang/go/tree/release-branch.go1.13/src

Why `StackGuardMultiplierDefault` was undefined in `/src/runtime/internal/sys/stubs.go`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding you cloned the Go source code from it's github and expecting it to work. It will not work.

You need to to follow Go guide [Installing Go from source](https://golang.org/doc/install/source) if you want to install it from the (github) source. Only cloning the repository is not enough, there are some required steps to be done after that.

Otherwise I suggest to install by using the available [binary distributions installer](https://golang.org/dl).

Detailed explanation: the const `StackGuardMultiplierDefault` is not found because the file where the const declared does not exists (the [zversion.go file](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/dist/buildruntime.go)). This particular file is only generated when `àll.bash` is executed (part of steps on installling Go from source).

Comment: I have solved this problem. It's my go environment variable .
thank you @mr ka